# Animation while going from a fragment to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have `text view` in the `fragment` when i click on text view an activity is called which takes me away to a new layout my doubt is. Is it possible to do animation while going from a fragment layout to activity layout.

Here is my **Fragment**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;`
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;



namespace TabbedApp
{
    public class IconTextCallFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);


        }

        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment 
            View view =inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.IconTxtCallLayout, container, false);
            var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.clickable_text_view);
            textView.Click += StartNewActivity;

            return view;
        }
        void StartNewActivity(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(Activity1));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            var trans = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

            trans.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.BounceTop, Resource.Animation.Slide_out, Resource.Animation.BounceTop, Resource.Animation.Slide_out);

            trans.AddToBackStack(null);
            trans.Commit();


        }

    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace TabbedApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "Activity1")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey put your animation  file  in resource/anim directory , by  doing this  way  you  can do   animation.

Comment: @jatDevta i have added it  but  i have just not added here thanks any more help will be appriciated

Comment: can any answer please